# sending a private message to your friends via Facebook IOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-messages, facebook-friends

I saw your post about sending messages to your Facebook friends via the IOS Facebook sdk,

I was wondering if there is a way to send a private message as well to these friends.

If not, is sending messages to your Facebook friends still supported from your previous post at:

[iOS Development: How can I get a Facebook wall post to show in the friend's news feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777214/ios-development-how-can-i-get-a-facebook-wall-post-to-show-in-the-friends-news)

If so let me know, thank you in advance

Comment: Absolutely impossible from Jan 2013, completely banned by Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/  You can only **send an email** (ie, private message) as explained by KLEW below.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to send a private message via facebook- just not with the SDK. You can get the user's 'username' (ie. http://www.facebook.com/username) and you can send them an email via your app to 'username@facebook.com'.

Shapow!

Major bonus: attach a file and it will be included in the facebook message.

One caveat: the email will not reach the recipient's message inbox unless the sender's email address is affiliated with a valid facebook user account. I would imagine this is in place to thwart spam.

Comment: Hoiw  can I get the user's username?

Comment: Graph API Provide user name. Thanks KLEW for now it is working :) +1

Comment: Note - this now goes to the "Other" section of a user's messages inbox and does not send them a notification. At this point it's pretty much useless.

Comment: If you are sending to one of your facebook friends, it won't go to the "Other" section, but rather, your main inbox.

Comment: @Maggesh how to get friend username please help

Comment: @KLEW i want to send text to fb user but users don't have username of fb account in my app. can i send text to fb user account?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to send private messages using the Graph API.

Yes, it is still possible to post to a friend's wall. I just checked it out just now using the graph API Explorer tool:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.  I used /friendId/feed with an HTTP post of "message" = "testing" and my friend confirmed they saw it on their stream.

Comment: In fact, it is now not possible - it was **deprecated by Facebook January, 2013**:  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Answer (score 0):

```
let messageDialouge = MessageDialog.init(content: <ShareContent>, delegate: nil)
   if messageDialouge.canShow {
        messageDialouge.show()
    }
```

And do add **fb-messenger-share-api** inside the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in info.plist