# Post message in user's friends wall in facebook iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios6

In my app i get the friends list of user and also post wall in friends wall.I had successfully got the friends list but when i posted in their wall.it couldn't work.
So Please Help me.

I got Error Like - error: domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5

I do many of searching and use many of code but it's not helped me yet.

Comment: Was completely banned by Facebook, early 2013 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665476/sending-a-private-message-to-your-friends-via-facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Please try to write the following code to in the ButtonAction

```
NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists", nil];

[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                           completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                               /* handle success + failure in block */
                                           }];
```

This might work. [Reference From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745474/integration-error-while-posting-message-on-friends-wall)