# How to post a message in facebook on a friends wall in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to post a message on a friends wall using `requestWithGraphPath:parameters:HTTPMethod:` method but its not working.

Here is my code,

```
-(void)shareAdOnFacebook
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setObject:@"Test post with silent authentication" forKey:@"message"];
    [params setObject:@"link" forKey:@"type"];
    [params setObject:@"http://yoursite.com" forKey:@"link"];
    [params setObject:@"Link description" forKey:@"description"];

    NSString *graphPath = @"[user_id]/feed";
    [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
}
```

There is no error but it doesn't post anything. I'm trying to get it to work on iOS5 and above.

Any advice?

Comment: you can implement the delegate and check the error

Comment: most common problem is trying to access this without oauth token.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists", nil];

[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                           completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                               /* handle success + failure in block */
                                           }];
```

Source from:[Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745474/integration-error-while-posting-message-on-friends-wall)

Comment: reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions is deprecated!