# FB message sending to friends on iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to send message to facebook friends on my iOS app. but i am unable to send.
My code is

```
NSMutableDictionary *postTest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[postTest setObject:@"Your message" forKey:@"message"];
[postTest setObject:@"" forKey:@"picture"];
[postTest setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
[postTest setObject:FACEBOOK_APP_ID forKey:@"app_id"];
NSString *userFBID =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"1649291866"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%@/feed?access_token=%@",userFBID,[FBSession activeSession].accessToken]
parameters:postTest
HTTPMethod:@"POST"
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
NSDictionary * result,
NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
    //[self hideHUD];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {// Success}

    }];

[postTest release];
```

can anyone please help me

Comment: Why are you unable to send?

Comment: its showing facebook error code 5

Comment: @PeterWarbo If you have some example or IDEA please share with me.

Comment: All explained here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665476/sending-a-private-message-to-your-friends-via-facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: Thanks Joe, But as I know we can not send message using graph API. But some apps like dropbox are doing this.