# Is it possible to post a message on the wall without a dialogue in iphone app using fbconnect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

I'm using facebook connect for my iphone application. I need to be able to post messages on the wall WITHOUT USING PROMPTING DIALOGUES. All i wanna do is enter text into a textfield and then post the text on the wall by clicking a button. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the tutorial here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#socialchannels

If you DON"T want to use dialogs then you need this.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/request/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/#publishing-methods

Also see this answer: [iOS Development: How can I get a Facebook wall post to show in the friend's news feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777214/ios-development-how-can-i-get-a-facebook-wall-post-to-show-in-the-friends-news/4777424#4777424)

Comment: no, that's not what i need... i'm using FBCONNECT as i said, it's different

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have successfully authenticated the facebook and you have a valid object  of facebook.

```
NSString *message = [yourTextField text];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message, @"message",nil];                          
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```