# iOS Facebook SDK post to friend's wall using standard dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Is it possible to post on friend's wall using the standard feed dialog or I have to create my own dialog for this?

UPDATE:
I know that it is possible to post to a friend's wall directly using requestWithGraphPath. But I'm trying to figure out if I can use the facebook dialog for this. For example Draw Something seems to be doing just that (see screenshot below). However, I tried sending 'target_id' as well as 'to' and neither works. Does anybody know how to do that?
[image]

Comment: hello can explain me how you developed above page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Just add "to" parameter with ID of the user you want to post to. I tested it works.

Comment: So, it looks like this doesn't work anymore? I still get the sheet, but nothing ever ends up posted. Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: "to" parameter helped me post to my friends wall. But is it possible to change privacy setting to "only me". Now it is published to "friends" even though I set it "only me" in the "Feed" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER :**

facebook annaunced that by 6.06.2013 it will not be possbile to post a friends wall via GraphAPI

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013

> Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API We will remove
>   the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API.
>   Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is
>   different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the
>   target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you
>   want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the
>   feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or
>   action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the
>   friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.

Comment: Will new change in facebook reflect in invite friends for join application?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very similar to [iOS Development: How can I get a Facebook wall post to show in the friend's news feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777214/ios-development-how-can-i-get-a-facebook-wall-post-to-show-in-the-friends-news)

Maybe that will help, as I think @kgutteridge has the right answer.

Comment: Mike, thanks for suggestion, but that answer doesn't help. Setting 'target_id' doesn't work.