# Posting an image on a Facebook fan page

Tags: ios, facebook, image, upload

I can't upload a picture using Facebook SDK for IOS....

I've retrieved the page id and I'm using the {Page_ID}/photos but the picture goes on my wall!!!

Then I've created an Album on the fan page and I'm trying to upload to {ALBUM_ID}/photos but the system return the message = "(#120) Invalid album id"!
Somebody have some ideas?!?

I've also setted the correct authorization (I suppose)!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777214/ios-development-how-can-i-get-a-facebook-wall-post-to-show-in-the-friends-news

Comment: improve your accepted rate..its just 25%

Comment: Sorry but I think that this response not match with my question!!!